Spawn bullets in different directions (Unity/C#)
I'm trying to create a half circle bullet spread (similar to the illustration attached IMAGE).
I'm not sure how to properly calculate angles. Right now what I have is a gun that can be aimed in any direction so I'm taking its rotation as a consideration as well. Then the bullet shoots at the direction is pointing at.
Here is the pseudo-code of what I currently have. But now, I don't know how to calculate angles and do a half circle bullet spread with respect to the current direction.
I've looked into tutorials like this but can't understand enough to apply to what I currently have.
intprojectileCount = 5;
Quaternion gunRotation = GetGunGlobalRotation();
 
for (var i = 0; i < projectileCount; i++)
{
     Projectile projectile = Instantiate(projectilePrefab);
     projectile.transform.position = gunBarrelPos;
     projectile.rigidbody.velocity = (gunRotation * Vector3.forward) * speed;
}

I've tried doing something like.
var angleStep = testAngle / projectileCount;
var angle = FP._0;


var direction = gunRotation * Vector3.forward;
var xDir = FPMath.Sin(angle * FP.Deg2Rad);
var zDir = FPMath.Cos(angle * FP.Deg2Rad);
var scatteredDir = new FPVector3(xDir, 0, zDir).Normalized;

direction += scatteredDir;
angle += angleStep;

projectile.rigidbody.velocity = direction * speed;

of course, this isn't working correctly. I've just been doing some trial and error so I'm not sure how to fix it.

Is it 2D half circle, or 3D half sphere?

@AlexeyS.Larionov this is a 3D gun that rotates in all direction, so I guess the correct answer is a 3D half sphere? :D

what is specifically wrong with what you have?

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/169893/how-do-i-implement-bullet-spread-in-three-dimensional-space

I don't really understand the way that you tried to do it, but I would probably do something like that:
for (int i = 0; i < projectileCount; i++)
{
    GameObject projectile = Instantiate(projectilePrefab, gunBarrelPos, gunRotation);
    Vector3 scatteredDir = new Vector3(Random.Range(-90,90),Random.Range(-90, 90), Random.Range(-90, 90));
    projectile.transform.Rotate(scatteredDir);
    projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity=projectile.transform.forward*speed;
}

This code instatiates the projectile with the rotation of the gun and just adds a random rotation to it. Then it makes it go into the direction it is facing and its done.

Yeah, that's simple enough and maybe sufficient for large number of bullets. But I think the OP wanted some equal spread of bullets

I dont really understand what I tried to do either but this is a very clean solution. I can work with this. Thank you very much for your help!
